# Google Api Calendar clear all Events

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

Google calendar api cannot clear all events gives error 'invalid. See my code below. Thank you.

Clearfunction in node.js

```
function clearCalendar(calendarId,auth) {

    var params = {
      auth,
      calendarId
    };

   return calendar.calendars.clear(params).then((res,err) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return err;
    }
    console.log('Event deleted.');
  });
  }
```

-result

```
 {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value"
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parms are incorrect you have an extra one. This method only accepts one parameter and the value is primary.

[calendars.clear](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/clear)

> Clears a primary calendar. This operation deletes all events associated with the primary calendar of an account.

## usage

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{CalendarId}/clear
```

## paramater ie calendar id

> calendarId string  Calendar identifier. To retrieve calendar IDs call the calendarList.list method. If you want to access the primary calendar of the currently logged in user, use the "primary" keyword.

As this only works on the users primary calendar you simply should send primary

```
function clearCalendar(auth) {


   return calendar.calendars.clear('primary').then((res,err) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return err;
    }
    console.log('Event deleted.');
  });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear all calendar events with node.js you can use the next code snippet:

```js
function clearCalendar(auth){

  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});

  calendar.calendars.clear({
      "calendarId": "primary"
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return err;
  });

}
```

Comment: is it just for primary Calendar ?

Comment: @CemilBirinci correct, this is your calendar, if you want to clear calendar events of your friend you need the *admin account*, so you can manage everything from there. Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk)